# How to cache images generated by imagick?

Tags: php, caching, imagemagick, browser-cache, imagick

I am using the function below to generate an image with text on it.  I am wondering how can I make it so that the image is only generated once for the user and then the image is cached in their browser.  My goal is to save server resources.

Also does my imagick code look okay? I am worried i might get some kind of memory leak.  Thanks for any help

```
function small_image($username){

$file_content = file_get_contents("https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/image.jpg");

$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick -> readImageBlob($file_content);

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( 'gray' );
$draw->setFillColor('white');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Utopia');
$draw->setFontSize( 50 );

$geo=$imagick->getImageGeometry(); 

$imagick->annotateImage($draw, 60, 185, 0, $username);

$imgBuff = $imagick->getImageBlob();
$imagick->clear(); 

$img = base64_encode($imgBuff);
$imagick -> destroy();
return "<img id='imagick-banner' width=500 alt='Embedded Image' src='data:image/png;base64,$img' />";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had mentioned saving server resources, so try making the client browser do the work.  A caveat of this method is that the user would have to have the correct font, or you'd have to provide the font on the website.

HTML

```
<canvas id="userImage"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("userImage");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageObject = new Image();
    imageObject.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 10, 10);
        context.font = "50pt Utopia";
        context.fillText(username, 60, 185);
    };
    imageObject.src = userImageURI;
    document.getElementById('userImage').appendChild(imageObject);
};
```

As a stricter answer using imagick try localStorage in JavaScript (have your php process it the first time and use JavaScript to decide when to ask for a new image).

```
localStorage.setItem("userImage", base64data);
var userImage = document.body.appendChild("img");
userImage.setAttribute('src', "data:image/png;base64, " + localStorage.getItem("userImage"));
```

Comment: I have been working on this but it only shows the top corner of my image and the text is cut off.  The image i use for imageObject is 1000 x 220.  I can get it to work by setting the canvas to 1000 x220 and imageObject to 1000 x 220, but is there some way to resize it proportionally to something like 400 x 105 ?

Comment: I can take a look tomorrow.  If I remember right I've done this through scaling in the past.  In the meantime can you set up a fiddle? I'd imagine the drawImage coordinates in my example are wrong and that's the initial issue.